# Getting the value of a hidden field

Tags: asp.net, hidden-field

I have an ASP.NET page with three hidden fields.  (Just one would do if I can get it to work. Just showing that I've tried several things.)

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenSkillId1" runat="server" />
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenSkillId2" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenSkillId3" runat="server"/>
```

I also have a JavaScript function that is being called by an AJAXControlToolKit.AutoCompleteExtender.OnClientItemSelected event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SkillPartialMatchSelected(source, eventArgs ) {
    document.getElementById("ctl00_Content_hiddenSkillId1").Value = eventArgs.get_value();
    document.getElementById("hiddenSkillId2").Value = eventArgs.get_value();
    document.getElementById("ctl00_Content_hiddenSkillId3").Value = eventArgs.get_value();
}
</script>
```

Using a break point and inspecting the values, I have confirmed that the vales are being set on the Client side.

Finally I have C# code behind for the page that is connected to a LinkButton OnClick event.

```
protected void AddSkillToProspect(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string selectedKey1 = Request.Form[hiddenSkillId1.ClientID];
   string selectedKey2 = Request.Form["hiddenSkillId2"];
   string selectedKey3 = Request.Form[hiddenSkillId3.ClientID];
   string selectedItem = SkillNameBox.Text.Trim();   
   ...
}
```

All three selectedKey values are null but the selectedItem value from the ASP.NET Text Edit has a value.

From what I've read, one of these should work. Am I missing something? What can I do to get the value from a JavaScript function on the client side back to the server side?

Comment: Do you really need to get the values via Request.Form? Wouldn't this work too: string selectedKey1 = hiddenSkillId1; string selectedKey3 = hiddenSkillId3; //but it won't work for hiddenSkillId2 because there is no runat=server.

Comment: If I knew what I was doing, lol, yes. I've been working old legacy for 8 yrs, just now learning web dev. I tried what you suggested based on answer below, didn't work. It ran OK, but data saved on client side not seen on server side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is related to case-sensitivity in JavaScript.  Although you have set the .Value for these fields, that is not the same as the .value.  Change your javascript to set the .value and you should be all set.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SkillPartialMatchSelected(source, eventArgs )     
{
    document.getElementById("ctl00_Content_hiddenSkillId1").value = eventArgs.get_value();
    document.getElementById("hiddenSkillId2").value = eventArgs.get_value();
    document.getElementById("ctl00_Content_hiddenSkillId3").value = eventArgs.get_value(); 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: That was it. Both answers were a piece of the puzzle, but this was the part I wasn't seeing myself.

Answer (score 3):

your hiddens controls have `runat=server` on them means they are server control and you can access them by their id in your code behind

this way the difference will `hiddenSkillId1` is a htmlserver control, `hiddenSkillId2` normal html control and this one `hiddenSkillId3` is an asp.net control

```
string selectedKey1 = hiddenSkillId1.Value;
string selectedKey3 = hiddenSkillId3.Text;
string selectedKey2 = Request.Form[hiddenSkillId2];
```

So please try using it this way

Comment: I'll try this but now I have another problem. Now my breakpoint in the JavaScript function in the OnClientItemSelected isn't being hit. It worked yesterday.

Comment: @SteveWash please show me the code for it or i don't mind you if you want to raise it as a new question

Comment: Its a VS setting somewhere. It must be set True on my laptop, where I was working yesterday. I can debug the Javascript part now (back on my laptop) and its hitting the breakpoint. The values are being assigned to the hidden fields on the client side, but its "" on the server side.